# Python/JSON: Merge default and user configuration

Tags: python, json, configuration

I'm using JSON configuration files in my python application. I want to have a default configuration with hierarchical layers.
The user configuration should only contain parameters which differ from the default.
My current solution is:

```
# default.json
{
    "parA" : 1,
    "parB" : {
       "sparA" : 0,
       "sparB" : 1
    }
}`

# user.json
{
    "parB" : {
       "sparB" : 9
    }
}
```

The configuration is loaded by

```
default_json = open("default.json")
default_config = json.load(default_json)
default_json.close()


user_json = open("user.json")
user_config = json.load(user_json)
user_json.close()  

config = default_config.copy()
config.update(user_config)
```

The problem with this is, that the whole key "parA" is overwritten, so that "sparA" is deleted.
Is there a simple way to overwrite only sub-keys but never overwrite the whole parent key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done, though it's a bit delicate.  The following assumes structural compatibility (e.g you're not trying to merge a non-dict into a dict, etc) and that in the case of non-dicts the "merge" is a simple replacement.

It also assumes it's OK to modify the base object in-place (it appears to be so since you're updating a copy anyway; if the latter is not the case it's no big deal, just add a copy statement such as `base_obj = dict(base_obj)` just before the `for` loops)...:

```
def selective_merge(base_obj, delta_obj):
    if not isinstance(base_obj, dict):
        return delta_obj
    common_keys = set(base_obj).intersection(delta_obj)
    new_keys = set(delta_obj).difference(common_keys)
    for k in common_keys:
        base_obj[k] = selective_merge(base_obj[k], delta_obj[k])
    for k in new_keys:
        base_obj[k] = delta_obj[k]
    return base_obj
```

This works for your given example, but would break if e.g with your given `default.json`, the `user.json` were, say, `'{"parB": 23}'` (merging a non-dict into a dict violates the structural compatibility constraint; I'm not sure what you'd **want** to happen in such a case).

So once you've tweaked the function to your exact specs, all you need is to replace, in your given code,

```
config.update(user_config)
```

with

```
config = selective_merge(config, user_config)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you! I'll take care of the structural compatibility, but as it is a configuration file, it shouldn't be a problem.